# Udemy course code doesn't work in Sublime. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: python, splicer

I'm taking a Udemy course on Python (my first language) and the environment of choice is Jupyter. When I try to write that code in Sublime, I can't get the same output (there are no errors). 
[image: Udemy code]

```
def splicer(mystring):
    if len(mystring)%2 == 0:
        return "Even"
    else:
        return "Odd"

names = ["Andy", "Eve", "Sally"]
list(map(splicer,names))
```

Comment: What is the output, and how is it different from the expected output?

Answer (score 3):

You need to print the result!

```
print(list(map(splicer,names)))
```

In Jupyter, it automatically prints the representation of a statement, where as when you're writing applications, you need to `print` if you want the result to be shown on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

jupyter acts as a python interpreter, so if you enter an object it automatically prints the result underneath. Sublime is a text editor, so it is only executing the code you are giving it. It is running `list(map(splicer,names))` but it is not displaying the object because you are not telling it to.

So the interpreter (jupyter) is executing your python code in real time and interpreting (printing to screen). The text editor is only executing your python code. Therefore, you need to add a print statement to your object to have the editor print the object to screen:

```
print(list(map(splicer,names)))
```